# WPF listbox two items side by side

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Basically I want to create a form. It might be a little long after I am done so I wanted to use a list box so the form is scrollable.  I would like to have a label with a text box next to it for input from the user. How can I have the label and text box side by side in the list box?

Also, if anyone has any other suggestions on how to create a form please let me know.

Comment: As Erno has noted you should not use a ListBox and your question is a bit vague, could you specify how you want to add new rows, if it needs to be dynamic and so on?

Comment: The rows should be static since The form will never change.  So I would need an easy way to edit the form since I wont be able to see the whole thing in the design view of visual studio 2010.

Comment: Well, by now the existing answers should be quite enough. Just use a Grid with two columns and however many rows your form needs and put that in a ScrollViewer, not much more to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use a ListBox to add scrolling capability, use the ScrollViewer for that.

Could you sketch/draw an image that explains your ideas?

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
         <Grid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=textBlock}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">_Name:</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                         x:Name="textBlock"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Text="Enter text here" />
            </Grid>                
            <Border Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="Anything you like" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

There are many other options. E.g., you could put the ScrollViewer inside the Border in my example. That would make the content of the Border scrollable instead of the entire form. Key is to determine what you want it to look like and how you want it to behave.

The best way to do that is by drawing or prototyping in a designer such as Expression Blend.

Comment: This looks like a good idea. Thanks! but is there a way to get put a label next to the text box?  This examples but the label on top of the text box and i would like it to be site by side so the label is associated with that particular text box.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your containing panel (e.g. Grid) in a ScrollViewer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx